# Number of ways you can form pairs of even-odd numbers, but not even-even nor odd-odd

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

Given an even number $n$ of pairs such that we always create $2n$ elements, we can group them total times of $P=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}=(2n-1)!!$. I would like to add a restriction to this: odd numbers can only be paired with even numbers.

Example: n=1 gives {1,2} so 1 pairing. n=2 gives {1,2,3,4} which I group into {(1,2),{3,4}} and {(1,4),{2,3}} so 2 pairings, for n=3 {1,2,3,4,5,6} gives {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)},{(1,4),(3,2),(5,6)},{(1,6),(3,2),(5,4)}, etc. and gives me 6 pairings

Somehow, by deduction, it seems that it should be $P=n!$ However, I do not have proper proof of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The parity and the order of pairs do not matter. For example, when n=2 {(1,2),(3,4)}, this is the same as {(2,1),(4,3)} and the same as {(4,3),(2,1)}.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, but I'll assume that you have $k$ distinct odd numbers and $k$ distinct even numbers.  Then, you can list the odd numbers and then there are $k!$ ways to list the $k$ even numbers to pair with them.  I don't know if you want the order of the pairs to matter or not, nor do I see why the parity of the number of pairs matters (note that you specify that $n$, the number of pairs, should be even, but then you use $n=1$ and $n=3$ as examples.).

Comment: @lulu I have edited the post to make it more clear: the order and the parity of the pairs do not matter, and we create always pairs of elements, therefore $2n$ elements

Comment: So, then my argument is complete, right?  I just used $k$ where you used $n$ (as I was not clear what your notation meant).  Note that your post still clearly states that $n$ must be even for some reason.  That's very confusing.

Comment: The question should say given $n$ pairs such that we always create $2n$ elements since you are allowing $n$ to be odd.

Comment: See that such a pairing corresponds to a bijection between odd and even numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange the odd numbers and even numbers in two different rows, eg for $3$ pairs,

$1\;3\;5$
$2\;4\;6$

Pairing them from left to right, the $1$ has three choices, two choices are left for the $3$, and $5$ has only one possible choice now, thus $3\cdot2\cdot1 = 3!$,

and generalizing for $n$ pairs, $n!$

Comment: I understand! Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Glad to be of help !$\;\;$ :)